# How to generate an exe from a python code on gitlab ci/cd

Tags: python, gitlab

I need to create a gitlab ci/cd for a python based project. On local, I am using pyinstaller to bundle everything up into an executable for windows and all works good.

```
pyinstaller app.py -F
```

Now I need to automate this exe generation whenever code is merged to master.

The catch is that I *do not* have access to a windows based gitlab runner. I only have access to a linux based runner.

Is there a a way to get this executable generated on gitlab ci/cd?

Comment: use some other CI service which has a windows runner?  or migrate to github and use the windows actions machine?  In general building windoze executables on anything other than the windows you plan to run them on is a recipe for disaster: more so with tools like pyinstaller which are pretty flaky anyway.  But you could try in wine.  Note that this really has nothing to do with ci: it would be the same doing it locally in e.g. Linux.

Comment: pyinstaller cant "cross-compile" https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=cross#pyinstaller-manual